Random Variables in the Neural Net diagrams
When I look at this discussion on linear regression:
What is a random variable and what isn't in regression models
It says:
If we have the population regression function:
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i$$
$Y_i$ is a RV, $X_i$ can be a RV or fixed, depending on how the data is collected and assumptions,
$\beta_0$,$\beta_1$ are fixed (under frequentist assumptions)
but our estimators $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ are typically random variables ; though after we do estimate them, they're fixed.
So now I want to look at the MLP, vanilla RNN and LSTM, assuming for regression
MLP:
input X, "weight" matrices W1,W2,output Y


RNN:
input X, "weight" matrices, hidden states H

LSTM:
input X, weight matrices, hidden state H,cell states C


So I am wondering how to think of the input, weight matrices, hidden states and cell states in terms of "random variables' vs "fixed/instance of RV". I do notice that writers in ML literature often don't try to distinguish these two.
But would it be accurate to take the same conventions from linear regression to this?
Population Regression Function:   weight matrices, hidden states and cell states are fixed,input and output are random variables.
Sample Regression Model: weight matrices, hidden states and cell states  are to be estimated by estimators, which make up our predictor(hence the estimators are random variables)
After they are Estimated: weight matrices, hidden states and cell states we estimated  are fixed.
So if these are true and I were to look at a random paper and see an architecture drawn out, what would it be being referring to? Is it something that could be any?

I’ll try and give a broad answer, but I’d be remiss if I didn’t start out by recommending Kevin Murphy’s book as an excellent introduction to a more statistically-minded view of ML
Now onto the actual question: it does make perfect sense to view NNs as analogous to regression models because they are regression models.
In regression you have paired observations $(Y_i,X_i)$ and assume a functional relationship of the form $Y_i = f(x_i)$. A neural network is just one approach to approximating $f$, and this is precisely the setting in which supervised learning takes place.
What’s “fixed” and what’s “random” is largely a matter of convention/perspective. In a frequentist paradigm, we assume that the parameters of the model are fixed - that there is some “true” underlying set of weights/biases - while the observations are random.

After they are Estimated: weight matrices, hidden states and cell states we estimated are fixed.

I think it would be more accurate to say that estimators are random conditional on the data, and are fixed once the data set is fixed. Calculating the point estimate is a computational problem.
We assume that there is a hypothetical “population level” weights matrix $W$, and idea behind frequentist estimators of $W$ is to use some function of the data to construct an interval that contains $W$ with high probability. The point estimate is drawn from that set via some rule. The sets themselves are confidence intervals, which tend to get thrown out in an ML context because they stop making sense as a consequence of the fitting procedure.
If the interval is tight then the point estimate should be very close to $W$, but it is still “random” in the sense that it depends on randomly sampled data. The idea behind resampling methods like the bootstrap is that you can get some sense of the distribution of the estimator without having to go out and gather more data. However the point estimate is still the “best” guess given the particular data set. The source of randomness in a frequentist estimator is the data itself, and things become “fixed” when we condition on an actual data set.

So if these are true and I were to look at a random paper and see an architecture drawn out, what would it be being referring to? Is it something that could be any?

If we view a neural network as an estimator for $f$ in the generalized regression problem, then architecture can be thought of as a set of constraints on $f$. Specifically we assume that $f$ can be represented as the composition of $N$ linear functions, where $N$ is the number of hidden layers, and each function is subjected to a transformation via some nonlinear activation function.
This is analogous to the constraints we place on $f$ in “vanilla” linear regression, where we assume that $f$ is a linear function in the parameter space, plus some Gaussian error term. The difference is that neural networks are much more flexible estimators that can representing much more complicated functions, but they are devilishly tricky to fit and generally require a slow and iterative train/test procedure to actually converge.
There is also the Bayesian view, in which a Bayesian neural network is a particular flavor of probabilistic graphical model, but I’ll refer back to Murphy’s book for a more detailed breakdown of that perspective.

So I am wondering how to think of the input, weight matrices, hidden states and cell states in terms of "random variables' vs "fixed/instance of RV".

The architecture gives an a-priori specification of hyperparameters like the number of hidden states and the types of layers (convolutional, fully connected, etc.). In a frequentist setting the input is randomly sampled, the population-level weights are fixed, and the estimated weights matrix is fixed after conditioning on the data.
I’m not familiar enough with RNNs to give a definitive answer on cell states, but I’d assume that we take them to be fixed given the data in a frequentist setting.

from what I understand, in Bayesian linear regression the population regression coefficients are RVs,
and in Bayesian neural nets it would be the population weights that are RVs.

if I were to be writing a tutorial where I distinguish between RV and fixed in my notation, and a I draw a generic diagram for an MLP or RNN; is the correct way to assume its the  "population regression function", or is that not too big a deal?

@a12345 yes, that's accurate - the difference between weights and regression coefficients is just a matter of terminology; mathematically they're the same exact thing. The population/sample distinction is a bit odd in a Bayesian framework - I think it's nicer to think of things in terms of a data-generating stochastic process vs. a particular realization of that process. We're not really assuming that there is a fixed population-level anything, just an underlying random process - in a bayesian setting, we're interested in the 'distribution' of a function rather than any fixed function

I also realized, another way to think about it that there's a  distinction between the formulas during training and during prediction. During prediction, the regression parameters (or weights and biases in Neural networks) are already estimated.
